# 2 column layout in css without float,position absolute

Tags: css, position, css-float

Anybody any ideas how to achieve this
I want this effect

```
<table>
  <tr><td width=100></td><td width=100></td></tr>
</table>
```

I can do it with float, or position absolute, but can it be done without these two?

Comment: Strange requirement - why don't you want to use those?

Comment: Could you explain your problem a bit further? You're trying to create 2-columns layout or what? Maybe CSS `display` property with value `table[-row|-cell]` will be fine?

Comment: Let me explain why i need it, its for wml and and they don't allow tables according to w3c, yes i can make tables with divs, tables etc. but haven't found  proper solution for CSS without float or position
( float isnt allowed either )

Comment: css3 has a solution for it
-moz-column-count: 2;
-webkit-column-count: 2;

but is not widely supported yet

Comment: why the down vote on the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

found a solution
css3 has a solution for it -moz-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-count: 2; but is not widely supported yet

Answer (score 3):

make use of a list displayed inline, fix margin and padding and it should work well. This will allow you to have more that two columns if you want to expand later.

```
<ul>
<li>First column</li>
<li>Second Column</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
li
{
display:inline;
}
```

Don't forget to put enough margin/padding to make it look better.

Comment: It's a better idea to make use of display: inline-block if you want to define width/height on your columns

Comment: Yes, use inline-block, but remember that IE 6-7 only supports inline-block on elements that are originally inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:table;">
    <div style="display:table-cell;"></div>
    <div style="display:table-cell;"></div>
</div>
```

of course except IE

Answer (score -2):

Tables should only be used for tabular information, you should avoid using tables for creating layouts, instead you should use DIV-based layouts. **[See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235029/should-i-use-table-or-ul/2235044#2235044)** for more details about this. Since you have asked for a solution *without floats, position (which means divs)*, the only other option we are left with is tables, so here is how you might go on to creating table based two column layout.

```
 <table width="60%" border="1" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td width="50%" align="left">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Colume One</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </td>

  <td width="50%" align="left">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Colume Two</td>
      </tr>
    </table>    
  </td>

 </tr>
</table>
```

Again, using tables for layouts is not a good idea :)

Comment: Tables are designed for tabular data - nothing more.

Comment: @Crozin: so quick man: read the title of the question again: I can do it with float, or position absolute, but can it be done without these two? He needs div-less solution which means tables. Think Again Please !!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Crozin: and i know what tables are supposed to do, see my score for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235029/should-i-use-table-or-ul/2235044#2235044. I have already answered this, so i know what it is all about, the quetioner needed table-based solution. Thanks again !!!!!!

Comment: Either my sarcasm detector is in dire need of complete re-calibration or this is the single most... ehm... *bewildering* answer I have seen all day.

Comment: If he need table-like behaviour he's supposed to use CSS `display` property (yeah, I know IE6 doesn't support it well). Using tables for layout design is wrong - **it's evil** - especially nested tables. btw: `width`, `border`, `align` - that should be moved to CSS.

Comment: @Crozin: and i know what tables are supposed to do, see my score for this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235029/should-i-use-table-or-ul/2235044#2235044. I have already answered this, so i know what it is all about, the quetioner needed table-based solution.

Comment: @Crozin: please go to this link and see my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235029/should-i-use-table-or-ul/2235044#2235044

Comment: @Crozin, @RegDwight: I have updated my answer because of the fact that you could not understand what i wanted to say through these comments, so please have a look at my updated answer above. Thanks a lot .......